# Split code into mutiple file Vs Single source code

Tags: python, html, database

My English is quite poor, Please ignore grammatical mistakes

A simple program that generates UI for user screen based on user activity and other recorded events.

The step involves.

- Getting activity from Db based as per user.
- Calculated UI components & data based on the above activity and event record.
- Generate HTML for every UI components based on data calculated above.

Each of this would require 100-120 lines of code. steps might increase based on the requirements.

Should I write the whole code base in a single file or split these steps into multiple files.